# Find contact ID by display name returning wrong ID

Tags: android, android-contacts

My code is returning ID = 1367(correct ID is 233). What is wrong? I have working code searching ID by phone number, but I need to change it to searching by display name.

```
String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" like'%" + mStructuredName +"%'";
                        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};
                        Cursor mcursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                projection, selection, null, null);

                        long idPhone = 0;
                        try {
                            if (mcursor != null) {
                                if (mcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                    idPhone = Long.valueOf(mcursor.getString(0));
                                }
                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (mcursor != null) {
                                mcursor.close();
                            }
                        }
                        if (idPhone > 0) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                            intent.setData(ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, idPhone));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
```

**Searching by phone number (working)**

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(tempPhoneNum));
                Cursor mcursor = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
                long idPhone = 0;
                try {
                    if (mcursor != null) {
                        if (mcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            idPhone = Long.valueOf(mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID)));
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (mcursor != null) {
                        mcursor.close();
                    }
                }

                if (idPhone > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                    intent.setData(ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, idPhone));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems too complicated, here is mine:

```
Cursor contacts_cur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME +" = ?",
            new String[]{name}, null);

contacts_cur.moveToNext();

 String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
```

Note that is seems dangerous for me to retrieve the id by name since two contacts can have the same name (but not the same id).